# Adding Stack.top() to a Vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stack, postfix-notation

I'm trying to implement an algorithm that takes a vector of type Token(Token is created in another .cpp file) and convert the infix expression given into a postfix expression.

```
static bool isOperator(const string& token){
    return token == "+" || token == "-" || token == "*" || token == "/" || 
    token == "%";
}
static int PrecedenceOf(const string& token){
    if(token == "+" || token == "-"){return 0;}
    if(token == "*" || token == "/"){return 1;}
    throw runtime_error("Unkown operator:" + token);
}

double eval_infix_expr(vector<Token> ie, map<string,double> sym_tab)
{

vector<Token> postfix_expr;
stack <string> stack;

while(!ie.empty()){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ie.size(); ++i){
            Token token = ie[i];
            if(!(token.type  == OPERATOR)){
                    postfix_expr.push_back(token);
            }else if(token.type == OPERATOR){
                     while (!stack.empty() && isOperator(stack.top()) &&
                                   PrecedenceOf(stack.top()) >= PrecedenceOf(token.value)){
                    //postfix_expr.push_back(stack.top()); stack.pop();
                  }
    stack.push(token.value);
            }
    }
}
Postfix_Evaluator pe(postfix_expr);
return pe.eval();
```

}

The line which is commented out is the only part of the program at the moment which is giving me difficulty, I am wondering how do I properly take the top of a stack and insert it into a vector?

Comment: How about using deque instead of stack? deque gives you a way to get and remove an item in onestep. And, I think you have to convert string type to Token type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `stack` and `vector` contain different types. The `stack` contains `string`, while the `vector` contains `Token`. You will need to construct a `Token` from a `string` as in:

```
postfix_expr.push_back(Token(stack.top()));
```

Of course you will need the appropriate constructor implemented in `Token`.

Also you shouldn't name your `stack` the same as its data type. Name it something like `tokenStack` as to avoid conflicts in the variable name and type with the compiler.

Comment: How do I construct a Token from stack.top()?

Comment: Still get an error because Token can't handle converting stack.top I also am not allowed to edit my Token struct, due to assignment constraints, I am stumped...

Comment: Show I make the type of stack <Token> then change the inputs of isOperator and Precedence to get the right outputs?

Comment: This seems like a viable solution. I believe that should work.

Comment: I'll be honest though I have no idea how to make isOperator and Precedence input the right type? I have fooled around with it before and only got more type errors. Any ideas?

Comment: I would have to see the Token class to make an educated guess. My guess is that you can somehow access the string stored in Token, so when you pass a Token to one of those functions access the internal string for your comparison to string literals. Might also need more SO questions :)